# Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'

Tags: sql, mariadb

I get the error from this line

```
SELECT table.field
FROM table
WHERE table.month = 'october'
AND DATEDIFF(day, table.start_date, table.end_date) < 30
```

The dates in my column are in the format m-d-yy

Do I need to convert this to a different format? If so how?

Using MariaDB

Comment: Is this SQL-Server? And what is the rest of your query? And what data type do these columns have?

Comment: Please show the full query, the full error message, and state which RDBMS you are using *(MS SQL Server, MySQL, PostGreSQL, etc)*.

Comment: I need to convert dates in the format d-m-yy to a unix date format. I think that would need regular expressions to place a 0 in front of a number if the month or day only has one digit.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

According to the documentation for MariaDB [`DATEDIFF`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/datediff/) only takes *two* arguments:

> **Syntax**
>
> `DATEDIFF(expr1,expr2)`
>
> **Description**
>
> `DATEDIFF()` returns `(expr1 – expr2)`
>   expressed as a value in days from one date to the other. `expr1` and
>   `expr2` are date or date-and-time expressions. Only the date parts of
>   the values are used in the calculation.

Answer (score 9):

@alex_b it is a very common observation to get confused between the syntaxes of the DATEDIFF & TIMESTAMPDIFF functions. 
Following [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff_mysql.asp) will certainly help with the syntax of DATEDIFF &
[this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) will list all the others date related functions available in MariaDB's parent MySQL.\

Referencing the links above below is a summary -

```
TIMEDIFF(expr1,expr2)
expr1 - '2000:01:01 00:00:00'
expr2 - '2000:01:01 00:00:00.000001'
```

> TIMEDIFF() returns expr1 − expr2 expressed as a time value. expr1 and
>   expr2 are time or date-and-time expressions, but both must be of the
>   same type.

```
DATEDIFF(expr1,expr2)
expr1 - '2007-12-31 23:59:59'
expr2 - '2007-12-30'
```

> DATEDIFF() returns expr1 − expr2 expressed as a value in days from one
>   date to the other. expr1 and expr2 are date or date-and-time
>   expressions. Only the date parts of the values are used in the
>   calculation.

Below is the scenario I used it for -

- using CURDATE for current date as 'argument1'
- using existing varchar column as 'argument2'
- using SET command to update a column

SET output_date = DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),input_date),
...
above worked for me. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

DATEDIFF of datediff returns a value which is the difference between two dates in terms of days. So datediff(mydate1, mydate2) will return X number of days; where mydate1 should be greater than mydate2. I believe the SQL query below will help you achieve your desired result.

```
SELECT table.field
FROM table
WHERE (table.month = 'october'
AND (datediff(table.end_date, table.start_date) < 30))
```