# Mariadb - calculate date difference in hour

Tags: sql, mariadb, datediff

Here is my initial code :

```
SELECT order_logs.order_logs_created, DATEDIFF(HOUR ,NOW(),order_logs.order_logs_created) FROM order_logs
```

And I gave an error :

```
#1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'
```

Then , I searched about MariaDB's DATEDIFF and I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250555/incorrect-parameter-count-in-the-call-to-native-function-datediff) , I figured out that I can use DATEDIFF with two parameters so I remove HOUR :

```
SELECT order_logs.order_logs_created, DATEDIFF(NOW(),order_logs.order_logs_created) FROM order_logs
```

I need time difference in hours , Actually it gives me in days. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use TIMESTAMPDIFF:

```
SELECT order_logs.order_logs_created, TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR ,order_logs.order_logs_created , NOW()) FROM order_logs
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `TIMESTAMPDIFF` for this:

```
SELECT 
    order_logs.order_logs_created,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,
        order_logs.order_logs_created,
        NOW())
FROM
    order_logs
```

Comment: I've already searched and reached my answer . But Thank you for your answer anyway. The essential difference between your answer any my own is position of now and created.