# SQL dateadd and datediff

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a SQL statement where it will return the number of record per day.

This my table

```
id |      ip       |       date
----------------------------------------
1   136.196.41.91   2017-01-01 11:08:14
2   28.158.146.198  2017-01-01 11:08:15
3   209.140.42.236  2017-01-01 11:08:16
4   241.184.227.171 2017-01-02 11:08:17
5   6.183.99.169    2017-01-02 11:08:18
6   105.18.254.15   2017-01-03 11:08:19
```

expected result something similar to:

```
2017-01-01: 3
2017-01-02: 2
2017-01-03: 1
```

I m trying this

```
select date, count(id)
from demo
WHERE date >=dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GetDate())-7,0)
GROUP BY date
```

But for some reason i'm getting this error in "phpmyadmin"

```
Error

SQL query: Documentation

select date, count(id)
from demo
WHERE date >=dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GetDate())-7,0)
GROUP BY date LIMIT 0, 25

MySQL said: Documentation
#1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'datediff'
```

I can't find what I'm doing wrong.

And i thought it might be from the date format, so i changed it into date only but with no luck.

Please advise.

Comment: it's mssql or mysql?

Comment: According to the documentation for Mysql [DATEDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) only takes two arguments while you are passing 3 arguments , Possible duplicate of [Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250555/incorrect-parameter-count-in-the-call-to-native-function-datediff)

Comment: What you trying in `WHERE` clause? What is your goal? according to your example and expected result, you just need simple grouping by DATE(`date`)

Comment: @Whencesoever, it's Mysql

Comment: @OtoShavadze my database contains the full date, meaning that if i grouped the table by date, it want be grouped if in the same day i have for exemple: 2017-01-01 11:08:14  && 2017-01-01 11:08:15.

Comment: @HassanAhmed, yes i can see that it takes 2 parameters, but everywhere i search for solution, they are always adding 3 parameters and i can't find out why. Even in the below answers they are adding 3 parameters

Comment: it's better to provide some samples of this solutions .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT DATE(`date`), count(*) FROM demo
GROUP BY DATE(`date`)
-- here your ordering criteria
LIMIT 0, 25
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what i was searching for.

Comment: Can you tell m sir how to use below query in MySQL .....DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -3 Month), INTERVAL 0 day,DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),SysUTCDATETIME()))

Comment: @Kapilsoni - Probably could better if you ask new  question about that

Comment: It possible via comment sir?

Answer (score 1):

In `MySQL` the `DATEDIFF` function only accepts 2 parameters:

```
DATEDIFF(date1, date2)
```

will return the difference betwee date1 and date 2 like `date1-date2`.

[See w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff_mysql.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff_mysql.asp)

Comment: yes i can see that it takes 2 parameters, but everywhere i search for solution, they are always adding 3 parameters and i can't find out why. Even in the below answers they are adding 3 parameters.

Comment: @Joey It depends on the SQL-Language you are using. `DATEDIFF` in `TSQL` expects 3 arguments, in `MySQL` only 2 arguments.

Comment: when removing one of the parameters, a new error is being generated:
#1305 - FUNCTION test.dateadd does not exist

Comment: @Joey In MySQL it's `DATE_ADD()` with an underscore.

Answer (score 1):

Check if this help,

`select date(date), count(*) from demo group by date(date);`

Comment: Thank you, this is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use GROUP BY Clause only :

SELECT date, count(id)
FROM demo
GROUP BY date

you need WHERE condition means : 

SELECT date, count(id)
FROM demo
WHERE DATEDIFF(your_datecolumn,GETDATE()) <= 0
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: the first one without "Where" gave me what i need, but this is only if the date field is formated as "date" and not "datetime". I prefer to solve it with the type "datetime".
the second one, with the where condition, gave me the same error as before.