# Laravel 8: query builder escapes the "greater than" operator

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm getting a MySQL error when trying to run a query through Eloquent.

FlightController.php:

```
$flightsToFinish = SrteFlight::whereRaw('DATEDIFF(MINUTE, NOW(), disc_time) > 15')->get();
foreach ($flightsToFinish as $flightToFinish)
{
    $flightToFinish->status = 1;
    $flightToFinish->save();
}
```

Error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:
1582 Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF' (SQL: select * from 
`srte_flights` where DATEDIFF(MINUTE, NOW(), disc_time) &gt; 15) in file
/var/www/vhosts/ar.ivao.aero/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 671
```

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the character is not escaped when doing the query, only when logged. You might have an HTML logger enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DATEDIFF just take 2 argument. (I think you misused SQL server syntax instead of MySQL syntax)

duplicate : [Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250555/incorrect-parameter-count-in-the-call-to-native-function-datediff)

[Sql Server syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp)

[Mysql syntax](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-datediff.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! You were right. I used TIMESTAMPDIFF instead.